# Tkinter Buttons are spread way to far apart, how to put them next to each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

When using Tkinter I run into an issue when making a few buttons on top of my screen saying "faq" "user manual" etc and they were too far apart, I tried changing the rows and columns, I thought it was because of the padding but it wasn't, I also even put them into a button frame thinking it would fix it but to no avail.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import methods as fn
from subprocess import call
#functions but most of other funcs are in a methods.py in the same folder

def close_root(): #kill func
    root.destroy()
    exit()

class Main: #Main class
    root = Tk() #init for main window
    root.title("TKL")
    root.configure(background = "#f16161")

    #row 0
    #photo
    logo = PhotoImage(file = "images/TK_logo.png")
    Label(root, image=logo, bg="#f16161").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady=5, sticky = W)

    #here is where the issue arises SO friends
    buttonframe = Frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 1) #toolbar on top of the window
    Button(buttonframe, text = "FAQ", command = fn.documentTKL, font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 5, height = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 5, sticky = NW)
    Button(buttonframe, text = "Manual", command = fn.documentTKL, font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 5, height = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 5, sticky = NW)
    Button(buttonframe, text = "add something here later", command = fn.documentTKL, font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 5, height = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 5, sticky = NW)

    #row 1
    Label(root, text = "\nTransKazLit", bg = "#f16161", fg = "white", font = "none 12 bold").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = W)
    Button(root, text = "Document to Text", command = fn.documentTKL, font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 20, height = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    Button(root, text = "Real Time Transliteration", command = fn.realtimeTKL, font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 20, height = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    #row 2
    Button(root, text = "Settings", font = "none 12", bg="#df9999", width = 20, height = 5).grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    #exit
    Button(root, text = "EXIT", font = "none 10", bg="#FF4C4C", width = 20, height = 5, command = close_root).grid(row = 10, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = W)

    root.resizable(1, 1)
    root.iconbitmap('images/TK_logo.ico')
    root.mainloop()
```

here's the code if you want to test it out and see what I mean specifically. its that particular triplet of buttons that doesn't seem to work properly, everything else works fine.

Comment: Have you looked into using `place` rather than `grid`? You could also set your buttons to `NW`, `N`, and `NE` in the same column. I don't really know your image size so I can only do so much as to replicating your issue.

Comment: Since the question is about layout, it would help if your example didn't depend on external modules and images.

Comment: @Axe319 `place()` is not the solution here. The OP just needs to a good `grid()` or `pack()` example to work with. `place()` should be reserved for very specific needs and in most other cases `grid()` and `pack()` are the correct choice for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of extraneous stuff in the code in your question, so it's not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), *plus* it's somewhat difficult to read because you're not following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

Nevertheless, I think at least part of the problem is because the line:

```
buttonframe = Frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 1) #toolbar on top of the window
```

assigns `None` to `buttonframe` because that's what the `grid()` method always returns. You then use that bogus value as the `parent` argument when creating the three `Buttons` within this toolbar.

Another problem arises from not understanding that this new frame has its *own* nested grid which is independent of the outer one (so any row and column values used for items in it should relative to its location).

Here's a modified version of your code addressing most of these issues:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#import methods as fn
from subprocess import call
# Functions but most of other funcs are in a methods.py in the same folder.

class Main:  # Main class.
    def __init__(self):
        root = self.root = Tk()  # Init for main window.
        root.title("TKL")
        root.configure(background="#f16161")

        # Row 0
        # Photo
        logo = PhotoImage(file="images/TK_logo.png")
        Label(root, image=logo, bg="#f16161").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky=W)
        Label(root, text='Logo Here', bg="#f16161").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky=W)

        btnframe = Frame(root, bg="#f16161")
        btnframe.grid(row=0, column=1) # Toolbar on top of the window.

        faq_btn = Button(btnframe, text="FAQ", command=fn.documentTKL, font="none 12",
                         bg="#df9999", width=5, height=1)
        faq_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky=NW)
        man_btn = Button(btnframe, text="Manual", command=fn.documentTKL, font="none 12",
                         bg="#df9999", width=5, height=1)
        man_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, sticky=NW)
        shl_btn = Button(btnframe, text="add something here later",
                         command=fn.documentTKL, font="none 12", bg="#df9999",
                         width=5, height=1)
        shl_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5, sticky=NW)

        # Row 1
        lbl = Label(root, text="TransKazLit", bg="#f16161", fg="white",
                    font="none 12 bold")
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
        btn = Button(root, text="Document to Text", command=fn.documentTKL,
                     font="none 12", bg="#df9999", width=20, height=5)
        btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=E)
        btn = Button(root, text="Real Time Transliteration", command=fn.realtimeTKL,
                     font="none 12", bg="#df9999", width=20, height=5)
        btn.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=E)

        # Row 2
        btn = Button(root, text="Settings", font="none 12", bg="#df9999", width=20,
                     height=5)
        btn.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=E)

        # Exit
        btn = Button(root, text="EXIT", font="none 10", bg="#FF4C4C", width=20, height=5,
                     command=self.close_root)
        btn.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

        root.resizable(1, 1)
        root.iconbitmap('images/TK_logo.ico')
        root.mainloop()

    def close_root(self):  # Kill func.
        self.root.destroy()
        exit()


Main()
```

Comment: Runley: Dunno how I missed it, but after taking another look at the answer I posted (and your question), it dawned on me that `Main` was a **`class`**, not a function, definition…and while using it the way shown "works", it's basically wrong with respect to how classes are supposed to be. In light of that, I've modified my answer so it defines and uses the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the buttons in a frame. You're attempting to do that, but you're doing it wrong. You're setting `buttonframe` to `None`, causing all of the buttons to be added to the root window.

Also, aligning things in a single row or column is typically easier with `pack` than with `grid`, so I recommend using `pack` to put the buttons in the button frame.

Change your code to look like the following. Note: For clarity, I removed code that is irrelevant to the layout problem.

```
buttonframe = Frame(root)
buttonframe.grid(row = 0, column = 1) 

faq_button = Button(buttonframe, text = "FAQ", ...)
manual_button = Button(buttonframe, text = "Manual", ...)
something_button = Button(buttonframe, text = "add something here later", ...)

faq_button.pack(side="left")
manual_button.pack(side="left")
something_button.pack(side="left")
```

In my experience, layout problems are much easier to solve when all of the layout code is in a separate block, rather than cramming as much code as you can on a single line.